# android studio gradle after git clone

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on a personnal Android Studio project from several places and I want to use git to sync my work.

The project is perfectly fine and working.

Please note that I only know basics about git but I can push to a github for instance.

So, after several commits, I got to my working directory and I ran those commands :

```
git init --bare D:/Dropbox/Git/myProject.git
git remote add dropbox D:/Dropbox/Git/myProject.git
git push -u dropbox --all
```

Then, on my other computer, I launch Android Studio and "import from version control" on the synchronized Dropbox git folder.

Here, all my classes are well imported but AS tells me to "Migrate Project to Gradle". Yet all my gradle files (project and modules) are in the good folders...

The [link AS provides](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) was not really any help, How can I activate Gradle in this case ?

Here is my **gitignore** file :

```
# Built application files
/*/build/

local.properties

.gradle/
.idea/
build/
gradle/
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove all of the gradle stuff from your .gitignore file. You need those.
Then add those files, commit them, and push them.

Finally, on the remote side, if you still have problems, open the build.gradle file as a project, instead of 'import from version control'.

Comment: thanks ! But then, why is all gradle files default in gitignore ? It doesn't really make sense to clone a directory without all plugins, isnt it ?